Checkbox CheckedChanged Firing Twice
I have a lot of checkboxes that are all connected to one event cause I want only one checkbox to be able to be "checked" at a time like you cant check multiple so when I check one I uncheck all the others but for some reason it shows the Notification twice for the checkbox that was checked and for the new checkbox that i just checked
private void Region_CheckedChanged(object sender, BunifuCheckBox.CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BunifuCheckBox checkbox = (BunifuCheckBox)sender;

    if (checkbox.CheckState == CheckStates.Checked)
    {
        string regionName = regionCheckBoxes[checkbox];

        Bufferly.Instance.BufferlyNotification.Show(
            Bufferly.Instance,
            $"You chose the Region {regionName}!",
            position: BunifuSnackbar.Positions.TopRight,
            type: BunifuSnackbar.MessageTypes.Success
        );

        foreach (var otherCheckbox in regionCheckBoxes.Keys)
        {
            if (otherCheckbox != checkbox)
            {
                otherCheckbox.CheckState = CheckStates.Unchecked;
            }
        }
    }
}


Can you add how you are setting up the multiple check boxes please? Are they all added/setup via the designer or is it done via code?

CheckedChanged is triggered when Checked state changes. Changing from Checked to Unchecked is a change, and changing from Unchecked to Checked is a change too. This is the reason why you see two notifications.
It looks like your code can already deal with that. But you could get read of "foreach" cycle if you use RadioButton control instead of Checkbox. If you select any RadioButton, all other RadioButtons in the same container will be uchecked automatically. If you have two separate groups of RadioButtons on the same form, you can put one of the groups (or both) inside GroupBox or Panel.

Checkboxes look more beautiful visually that's why I chose them any idea on how I can avoid the two notifications?

The good thing about RadioButton is that user will immediately know that only one can be selected. CheckBox are typically used to control independent properties, and users will need to get used to the idea that only one can be checked.

Use the CheckedChangedEventArg instead of the sender:
if (e.CheckState == BunifuCheckBox.CheckStates.UnChecked) return; 

var checkbox = (BunifuCheckBox)sender;
string regionName = regionCheckBoxes[checkbox];

Bufferly.Instance.BufferlyNotification.Show(
    Bufferly.Instance,
    $"You chose the Region {regionName}!",
    position: BunifuSnackbar.Positions.TopRight,
    type: BunifuSnackbar.MessageTypes.Success);

foreach (var otherCheckbox in regionCheckBoxes.Keys)
{
    if (otherCheckbox != checkbox)
        otherCheckbox.CheckState = CheckStates.Unchecked;
}


Still firing twice it sends the notification for the one i had previously checked and the one i just checked

Debug the event and look at the sender to confirm it is the previously selected button event handler firing and not the clicked one firing twice. If it is the previous selected sender firing, in what order do the events trigger, new->original or original->new?

Also, what is the code/variable behind this? regionCheckBoxes[checkbox]  That looks like a dictionary lookup, but using a control as a key??  The other thing to check is any accidental use of = CheckStates.Checked instead of == CheckStates.Checked, for instance some other code called in this process that is meant to inspect the checked state but actually assigns. Looking at the call stack of each call might reveal something.

It fires previously selected -> newly selected

here is the code https://pastebin.com/dVPWMC6e

In the user control designer you don't have any event wiring for these 20 or so checkboxes declared in the UI? The fact it is firing the previous before the newly selected is definitely unusual. Are all unchecked at start? Where checking 1 triggers 1 event, the second selection re-triggers the first, then the 2nd, what about the third selection? (raises 2nd then 3rd events?)

For now all are unchecked on start but in the future I would save the last checked in the config and check it on load but doesnt seem to work as intended
